# How to pivot a table using SQL - Unrecognized value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a table using SQL. My table looks like this:

| ID | import | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cust1 | 100 | Authorized |
| cust1 | 10 | Authorized |
| cust2 | 20 | Rejected |
| cust3 | 15 | Authorized |
| cust3 | 70 | Rejected |

And the expected outcome is this one:

| ID | Authorized | Rejected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cust1 | 110 | null |
| cust2 | null | 20 |
| cust3 | 15 | 70 |

I'm using the following code, but for some reason I can't make it work:

```
select id_account,[Authorized],[Rejected]

from 
(select id_account, import, status_name as status,
  from `mytable` t7
  where transaction_type_code in (6,9) and authorization_date > '2022-06-01' and authorization_date <= '2022-06-30') 
  as src

pivot
  (sum(import) for status in ([Authorized], [Rejected])) as pvt
```

The error I get is that it doesn't recognize [Authorized], but it's one of the options that I have on the status_name column. More specifically, the error says: Unrecognized name: Authorized at [17:26]

Does anybody know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: I've read a similar case that had an issue with the column they tried to use being a nested column. Could this be it?

Comment: @BeRT2me sorry, I'm not sure which SQL version I'm using. I'm using BigQuery, I don't know if this is helpful in any way

Comment: BigQuery is perfect, I see you already added the tag~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide pivot columns as string literals. Consider below query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, import, status FROM mytable
) PIVOT (SUM(import) FOR status in ('Authorized', 'Rejected'));
```

[image]

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator

Comment: Thank you so much! I had seen a lot of examples where the columns were between [ ] so I thought that was the correct way to do it, but your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Some of dbms uses brackets to quote special characters in column names. :-)